# Probability of both and at least one?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

On conditional probability - let's say there's two events $A$ and $B$ with probabilities $\Pr(A)$ and $\Pr(B)$. Is the conditional probability

> $$\Pr(A\cap B | A\cup B) = \frac{\Pr\big((A\cap B)\cap(A\cup B)\big)}{\Pr(A\cup B)} = \frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(A\cup B)}\text?$$

I.e., is the probability of both events happening "and" at least one event happening equivalent to the probability of both events happening?

Comment: Conditional probabilities Pr$(C\mid D)$ should be interpreted as the probability that C occurs *given* D occurring, not the probability that C occurs *and* D occurs.

Comment: "Both and at least one" is exactly the same as "both"!

Comment: I don't like that "'and'" even in quotes.  $P(M|N)$ is *not* the probability of $M$ and $N$.  It is the probability of $M$ given that $N$ has occurred.  Yes it mean both $M$ and $N$ occured but as we are removing all instances of $N$  not occuring from the universe it is *not* at all the probability of $M$ and $N$.  That probability allows for the possibility of neither or $M$ without $N$ which we are *not* considering.

Comment: In other words, the text you write:  "I.e., is the probability of both events happening "and" at least one event happening equivalent to the probability of both events happening"  is a completely different and incorrect interpretation of the math you wrote "$\Pr(A\cap B | A\cup B) = \frac{\Pr\big((A\cap B)\cap(A\cup B)\big)}{\Pr(A\cup B)} = \frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(A\cup B)}$"

Comment: Oh.... you are asking if $P(A\cap B) = P([A\cap B]\cap [A\cup B])$ is true to justify the larger equation.   Yes.  As $[A\cap B]\cap [A\cup B] = A\cap B$ then probability is the same.   But that is only a *component* of your equation and is *not* an interpretation of either $Pr(A\cap B|A\cup B)$ or of $\frac {Pr(A\cap B)}{Pr(A\cup B)}$.  .... It made you question actually very unclear.

Comment: The mods changed the format of my question - I wrote `P(both | at least one) = P( both and at least one) / P(at least one) = P(both) / P(at least one)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(A\cap B) \subset \begin{cases}A\\B \end{cases} \subset (A\cup B)$ so $(A\cap B)\subset (A\cup B)$.

And if $M \subset N$ then $M\cap N= M$.  I.e. the interection of a subset with its superset is the subset as it is completely contained in it.

So $(A\cap B) \cap (A\cup B) = (A\cap B)$

....

And if $M = N$ the $P(M) = P(N)$ as they are the exact same thing.

....

So yes we can presume $P([A\cap B]\cap [A\cup B]) = P(A\cap B)$.

.....

So if we do the following

$P(A\cap B|A\cup B) \underbrace{=}_{\text{conditional probability law}}$

$\frac {P\color{blue}{([A\cap B]\cap [A\cup B])}}{P(A\cup B)} \underbrace{=}_{\color{blue}{([A\cap B]\cap [A\cup B])} = \color{green}{A\cap B}}$

$\frac {P\color{green}{(A\cap B)}}{P(A\cup B)}$

that is valid conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are correct. $$\Pr(A\cap B | A\cup B)=\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(A\cup B)}$$

[image]